# Django many-to-many

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
      return self.name


class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    actors = models.ManyToManyField(Actor)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

how can I access to the movies of an actor from Actor object in a template ?

I need to do it in both directions.

This worked from movies to actors.

```
{{movie.actors.all}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just put `related_name` into `actors` field

```
actors = models.ManyToManyField(Actor, related_name="actor_movies")
```

and then in template:

```
{{ actor.actor_movies.all }}
```

or if you dont want `related_name`:

template:

```
{{ actor.movie_set.all }}
```